# Object List on RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, loops, object, android-recyclerview

I'm having a little big problem on Android Studio. A have an object "Sport" that can have multiple lessons. So inside this object there is a list.

```
public class Sport implements Serializable {

    private String cid;
    private String cname;
    String csportpic;
    long ccreatedat;

    List<Lesson> lessons;

    public Sport() {

    }
```

The object has gets and sets for each element. So the data coming from Firebase in well placed.

In a recycleview I want to display the lessons data and also some variable of the object sport(cname, cid), so I'm passing to the recycleview constructor the object Sport.

Do you have any ideia how to perform a loop through lesson List in a recyclerview? Can it be done inside onBindViewHolder?

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: I have tried to loop using inside and outside of the onBindViewHolder. I thought that unsing for each loop would solve it.  For each to run through the list<Sport> and passing to the adapter the current loop sport.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,  got it working.

For some reason the first loop was not working correctly. Perhaps the Object was not well written, or the query to the database.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CoachVH holder, final int position) 
{
    for (Lesson lesson:sportlesson.get(position).getLessons()) 
    {
        holder.classid.setText(String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").format(lesson.getLessonTime())));

        holder.classname.setText(sportlesson.get(position).getCname());

        holder.classaddress.setText(String.valueOf(lesson.getLessonAddress()));

        holder.classprice.setText(String.valueOf(lesson.getLessonPrice()));
    }
}
```